# Validation accuracy/loss goes up and down linearly with every consecutive epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a CNN in keras with tensorflow backend with the following model architecture for a binary classification problem. I've divided approximately 41k images into training, validation and test sets in the ratio 70:25:5 giving 29k images in train set, 10k in validation and 2k in test set.

There is no class imbalance, there were approximately 20k samples in each of `pos` and `neg` classes.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding = 'same', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (7, 7), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=3e-5),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='checkpointORCA_adam-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5,
                              patience=20, min_lr=1e-8)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

# Change the batchsize according to your system RAM
train_batchsize = 32 # changed them to 64 and 128 respectively, but same 
                      results
val_batchsize = 32

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_path,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=train_batchsize,
    class_mode='binary',
shuffle=True)

# train_generator.reset()
# validation_generator.reset()
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_path,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=val_batchsize,
    class_mode='binary',
shuffle=False)

# validation_generator.reset()

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_lr])
```

These are the epochs for the training progress, where the validation accuracy flucatuates in a linear fashion. It first gets high and then low by nearly the same amount. What could be the reason for this?

I've checked out nearly every other answer for this, and my data is normalized, properly shuffled in the training set, lr is small and very well checked in within what other researchers in similar problem domain found success with.

```
Found 29124 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 10401 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/60
910/910 [==============================] - 530s 582ms/step - loss: 0.6105 - acc: 0.6161 - val_loss: 0.2298 - val_acc: 0.9548
Epoch 2/60
910/910 [==============================] - 520s 571ms/step - loss: 0.3590 - acc: 0.8480 - val_loss: 0.8340 - val_acc: 0.6604
Epoch 3/60
910/910 [==============================] - 520s 571ms/step - loss: 0.3160 - acc: 0.8695 - val_loss: 0.0983 - val_acc: 0.9558
Epoch 4/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 580ms/step - loss: 0.2925 - acc: 0.8830 - val_loss: 0.5063 - val_acc: 0.8385
Epoch 5/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.2718 - acc: 0.8895 - val_loss: 0.0541 - val_acc: 0.9745
Epoch 6/60
910/910 [==============================] - 530s 583ms/step - loss: 0.2523 - acc: 0.8982 - val_loss: 0.5849 - val_acc: 0.8060
Epoch 7/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 580ms/step - loss: 0.2368 - acc: 0.9076 - val_loss: 0.0682 - val_acc: 0.9695
Epoch 8/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 582ms/step - loss: 0.2168 - acc: 0.9160 - val_loss: 0.6503 - val_acc: 0.7660
Epoch 9/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1996 - acc: 0.9213 - val_loss: 0.0339 - val_acc: 0.9850
Epoch 10/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1896 - acc: 0.9258 - val_loss: 0.5710 - val_acc: 0.8033
Epoch 11/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1814 - acc: 0.9285 - val_loss: 0.0391 - val_acc: 0.9834
Epoch 12/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1715 - acc: 0.9342 - val_loss: 0.6787 - val_acc: 0.7792
Epoch 13/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1678 - acc: 0.9361 - val_loss: 0.0451 - val_acc: 0.9796
Epoch 14/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1683 - acc: 0.9356 - val_loss: 0.7874 - val_acc: 0.7306
Epoch 15/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 580ms/step - loss: 0.1618 - acc: 0.9387 - val_loss: 0.0483 - val_acc: 0.9761
Epoch 16/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1569 - acc: 0.9398 - val_loss: 0.9105 - val_acc: 0.7060
Epoch 17/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1566 - acc: 0.9397 - val_loss: 0.0380 - val_acc: 0.9853
Epoch 18/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1506 - acc: 0.9416 - val_loss: 0.7649 - val_acc: 0.7435
Epoch 19/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 580ms/step - loss: 0.1497 - acc: 0.9429 - val_loss: 0.0507 - val_acc: 0.9778
Epoch 20/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1476 - acc: 0.9439 - val_loss: 0.7189 - val_acc: 0.7665
Epoch 21/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1426 - acc: 0.9447 - val_loss: 0.0377 - val_acc: 0.9873
Epoch 22/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 580ms/step - loss: 0.1407 - acc: 0.9463 - val_loss: 0.7066 - val_acc: 0.7817
Epoch 23/60
910/910 [==============================] - 526s 578ms/step - loss: 0.1427 - acc: 0.9444 - val_loss: 0.0376 - val_acc: 0.9877
Epoch 24/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 580ms/step - loss: 0.1373 - acc: 0.9467 - val_loss: 0.6619 - val_acc: 0.8023
Epoch 25/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 580ms/step - loss: 0.1362 - acc: 0.9466 - val_loss: 0.0457 - val_acc: 0.9844
Epoch 26/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 582ms/step - loss: 0.1350 - acc: 0.9474 - val_loss: 0.8683 - val_acc: 0.7046
Epoch 27/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1339 - acc: 0.9492 - val_loss: 0.0411 - val_acc: 0.9855
Epoch 28/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1339 - acc: 0.9499 - val_loss: 0.9552 - val_acc: 0.6762
Epoch 29/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1343 - acc: 0.9488 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_acc: 0.9859
Epoch 30/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 580ms/step - loss: 0.1282 - acc: 0.9513 - val_loss: 0.8127 - val_acc: 0.7298
Epoch 31/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1286 - acc: 0.9504 - val_loss: 0.0484 - val_acc: 0.9857
Epoch 32/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1258 - acc: 0.9506 - val_loss: 0.5007 - val_acc: 0.8479
Epoch 33/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1301 - acc: 0.9495 - val_loss: 0.0467 - val_acc: 0.9859
Epoch 34/60
910/910 [==============================] - 529s 581ms/step - loss: 0.1253 - acc: 0.9516 - val_loss: 0.6061 - val_acc: 0.8056
Epoch 35/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1259 - acc: 0.9521 - val_loss: 0.0469 - val_acc: 0.9873
Epoch 36/60
910/910 [==============================] - 528s 580ms/step - loss: 0.1249 - acc: 0.9511 - val_loss: 0.8658 - val_acc: 0.7121
Epoch 37/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1206 - acc: 0.9548 - val_loss: 0.0459 - val_acc: 0.9869
Epoch 38/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 580ms/step - loss: 0.1229 - acc: 0.9512 - val_loss: 0.4516 - val_acc: 0.8646
Epoch 39/60
910/910 [==============================] - 527s 579ms/step - loss: 0.1206 - acc: 0.9528 - val_loss: 0.0469 - val_acc: 0.9861
Epoch 40/60
```

The below graph is not for this problem but similar situation of what I'm asking about:

[image: loss]

[image: acc]

Comment: Can you post the code where you are generating the labels for your training and validation set?

Comment: The labelling was done manually in the ratio 70:25:5

Comment: How many samples are there? What is the batch size? Are you using stratified shuffling/splitting? Is there a class imbalance?

Comment: Iv'e added those now @Vitrioil

Comment: Okay, can you try reducing learning rate and lower the dropout?

Comment: Making lr 3e-4 or 3e-6 doen't work well. I'll try with lowering the dropouts, but it doesn't affect the validation set, so why do you think it would work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things I tried to get the curve as below:

[image]

- Reduced the model's capacity to a few layers with few neurons.
- Lowered the learning rate and increased my batch size from 32 to 128.

This may not be the only possible solution, but I present a few easy tips to get things right. Helpful links: [1](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/unstable-validation-loss-with-constantly-decreasing-training-loss/32548) and [2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47735/why-does-my-minimal-cnn-example-show-strongly-fluctuating-validation-loss)

I am also planning to train for more epochs.